# MySQL aborted conection unknown error

Tags: mysql

I use multi jdbc to exec full table queries for data migration. When I use parallel 75 jdbc to query diff tables which has nearly 3000000 rows per table, I found MySQL abort one connection before all the data are returned back to jdbc.

Slow log:

```
Time: 160919  9:09:38
User@Host: test[test] @  [10.142.90.20]
Thread_id: 349  Schema: mmig_1005  QC_hit: No
Query_time: 161.997180  Lock_time: 0.000560  Rows_sent: 619246  Rows_examined: 619246
Full_scan: Yes  Full_join: No  Tmp_table: No  Tmp_table_on_disk: No
Filesort: No  Filesort_on_disk: No  Merge_passes: 0
explain: id   select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    Extra
explain: 1    SIMPLE  CAR_NEW_6       ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2923495 
use mmig_1005;
SET timestamp=1474247378;
SELECT @@version, name, id, sharding_id, model
FROM CAR_NEW_6;
```

There are nearly 3000000 rows in table mmig_1005.car_new_6, but MySQL just sent 619246 rows and aborted this connection. The thread id is 349, and then I found this aborted connection 349 in the mysql-err log.

```
160919  9:09:38 [Warning] Aborted connection 349 to db: 'mmig_1005' user: 'test' host: '10.142.90.20' (Unknown error)
160919  9:09:38 [Warning] Aborted connection 305 to db: 'mmig_1001' user: 'test' host: '10.142.90.20' (Unknown error)
```

MySQL parameters:

```
connect_timeout 10
deadlock_timeout_long   50000000
deadlock_timeout_short  10000
delayed_insert_timeout  300
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    45
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
interactive_timeout 1800
lock_wait_timeout   600
net_read_timeout    7200
net_write_timeout   7200
rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout    10000
slave_net_timeout   30
sqlasyntimeout  10
sqlasynwarntimeout  3
thread_pool_idle_timeout    60
wait_timeout    1800
innodb_log_buffer_size  134217728
max_allowed_packet  1073741824
```

Why does MySQL abort this connection before its data are all sent?

Comment: One query lasted longer than 30 minutes?

Comment: @Drew,Only serval miniutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be way off base but here goes. From the MySQL manual page entitled [Communication Errors and Aborted Connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/communication-errors.html):

> If a client successfully connects but later disconnects improperly or
>   is terminated, the server increments the Aborted_clients status
>   variable, and logs an Aborted connection message to the error log. The
>   cause can be any of the following:
>
> - The client program did not call mysql_close() before exiting.
> - The client had been sleeping more than `wait_timeout` or
>     `interactive_timeout` seconds without issuing any requests to the
>     server. See Section 6.1.5, “Server System Variables”.
> - The client program ended abruptly in the middle of a data transfer.
>
> Other reasons for problems with aborted connections or aborted
>   clients:
>
> - The `max_allowed_packet` variable value is too small or queries require
>     more memory than you have allocated for mysqld. See Section B.5.2.10,
>     “Packet Too Large”.

Regardless of the `max_allowed_packet` you are showing or attempts at increasing it, I suggest a revisited strategy in attempts at chunking it down into segments.

Comment: I see this page before,max_allowed_packet has set to the max value 1g.

Comment: this connection is trans data ing!not idle,and after this happen,client got an IOException:Connection reset by Peer!means mysql has abort the connection first,not the client abort the connection!

Comment: Perhaps the *or queries require more memory than you have allocated for mysqld* ... chunk it down

Comment: PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                            
14984 apps      20   0  108g  43g 7980 S  0.3  8.6  42:45.33 mysqldinnodb_buffer_pool_size 85899345920